# How to set my website name or alias name instead of google oauth client_id from the response?

Tags: oauth

When i get the response from google contacts API using Oauth2.0, it Returns the response something like as follows

"The site **251543634636.apps.googleusercontent.com** is requesting access to your Google Account for the product(s) listed below. ...etc"

In which, how to display my web application name in place of client_id like **251543634636.apps.googleusercontent.com**

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue, has anyone been able to solve this?

Comment: The answer worked for me

Answer (score 7):

All you need to do is register your application, and then a more friendly description can show up for the user.  Instructions on how to do this are documented here:

http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/RegistrationForWebAppsAuto.html

Note the section that says:

> Domain description: This optional value should briefly describe the
>   domain you're registering. In the future, this description may be
>   displayed on the Google Access Consent page to provide additional
>   information for your users. You always have the option of changing
>   this description or leaving it blank.

Good luck!